# Changing the bibliography output from single curly quotes to single straight quotes

Tags: bibtex

I need to output *article titles* in my `\bibliography` surrounded by straight quotes `'` rather than curly quotes `‘`.

Must this be done in the preamble or in the `.bst` file, or some other means?

I can't find any way to change this on a document level.

---

The relevant section of code that deals with quotes is as follows (afaik):

```
}

FUNCTION {quote}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "`" swap$ * "'" * }
  if$
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which bibliography style you employ at present.

Comment: Hard to say with certainty with that little information to go by (it would really help if you could tell us how you generate your bibliography at the moment), but generally speaking if you are using BibTeX this is going to be controlled by the `.bst` file and most likely the quotation marks are hard-coded there, so need to be changed there. (Barring solutions that redefine the quotation mark characters directly - which may or may not be a good idea.)

Comment: I'm using a modified version of the BibTeX [agsm](http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/bibtex/agsm.bst) bibliography style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a fairly recent version of LaTeX the single straight quotation mark is available our of the box as `\textquotesingle` (with older LaTeX kernels you may want to load `\usepackage{textcomp}`).

Then you just need to replace `'` and `` ` `` with `\textquotesingle{}` in your definition of `quote`

```
FUNCTION {quote}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\textquotesingle{}" swap$ * "\textquotesingle{}" * }
  if$
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @moewe for your solution which appears to work well for me.

Comment: @MarcusPhelan If the answer helped you solve your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking on the green checkmark on the top left. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.